# How to concat or sum the fields of objects collection referenced as @OneToMany in JPA Entity with CriteriaBuilder?

Tags: java, jpa, criteria-api, jpa-criteria

I have two JPA Entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "registry_group")
public class RegistryGroupEntity {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="registry_groups_gen", sequenceName="registry_groups_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator="registry_groups_gen")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "registryGroup")
    private Collection<ServiceEntity> services;

}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "services")
public class ServiceEntity {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="service_gen", sequenceName="services_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator="service_gen")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String name;    
}
```

I'd like to represent the selection as `RegistryGroupRow` class object:

```
public class RegistryGroupRow {
    private Long id;
    private String name;    
    private String serviceNames;

    public RegistryGroupRow(Long id, String name, List<String> serviceNames) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.serviceNames = serviceNames;
    }
}
```

I have a function like that:

```
public List<RegistryGroupRow> getRegistryGroupRows(RegistryGroupFilter filter, Integer offset, Integer limit) {

    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<RegistryGroupRow> c = cb.createQuery(RegistryGroupRow.class);
    Root<RegistryGroupEntity> registryGroup = c.from(RegistryGroupEntity.class);


    c.multiselect(registryGroup.get(RegistryGroupEntity_.id),
            registryGroup.get(RegistryGroupEntity_.name),
            registryGroup.get(RegistryGroupEntity_.services) //problem is here
    );
```

It wouldn't work, as `RegistryGroupEntity_.services` is a collection of `ServiceEntity`, but I need a concatenation on `ServiceEntity._name` here. How I can call something like  `cb.concat(registryGroup.get(RegistryGroupEntity_.services).get(ServiceEntity._name))` for the last parameter of the `RegistryRowGroup` constructor? How to make `CriteriaBuilder` to run through the collection's objects specific field and collect/concat/sum its values?

For concat I'd like to concat with separator to `String`. For collect I'd like to collect into `List<String>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach**

One way to solve this issue is to use a native sql function to do the aggregation of the service names.

E.g. in H2 database, there is a function named [`LISTAGG`](https://www.h2database.com/html/functions-aggregate.html#listagg) which takes 2 parameters, first the field to aggregate and second the delimiter. I am certain whichever database you are using have something similar to aggregate data; e.g. in postgres there is `string_agg(expression, delimiter)`.

**Prerequisites**

The function from the database needs to be registered and mapped to a name in hibernate. A custom dialect can be created or a `MetadataBuilderContributor` can used to achieve the same. The `MetadataBuilderContributor` is *neaty* so here we are..

```
// Registering the function LISTAGG under the name 'listagg'
public class H2SqlFunctionContributor implements MetadataBuilderContributor {

    @Override
    public void contribute(MetadataBuilder metadataBuilder) {
        metadataBuilder.applySqlFunction(
                "listagg",
                new StandardSQLFunction("LISTAGG", StandardBasicTypes.STRING)
        );
    }
}
```

Update the spring properties file to include the `MetadataBuilderContributor` usig the fully qualified name of the class as such;

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.metadata_builder_contributor = com.stackoverflow.q75989598.H2SqlFunctionContributor
```

Update the class `RegistryGroupRow` to use this constructor;

```
public RegistryGroupRow(Long id, String name, String serviceNames) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.serviceNames = serviceNames;
}
```

**Querying part**

Assuming `RegistryGroupEntity` looks as such:

```
public class RegistryGroupEntity {

    @Id
    private long id;

    // using 'groupName' to makes it distinctive in the queries to come
    @Column
    private String groupName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "registryGroupEntity")
    List<ServiceEntity> serviceEntities;
}
```

And `ServiceEntity` looks as such:

```
public class ServiceEntity {

    @Id
    private long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @JoinColumn(name = "registry_group_id")
    @ManyToOne
    private RegistryGroupEntity registryGroupEntity;
}
```

The quering will be as follows;

```
// the usual stuffs
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<RegistryGroupRow> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(RegistryGroupRow.class);
Root<RegistryGroupEntity> registryGroup = criteriaQuery.from(RegistryGroupEntity.class);

// Create a join on the entity ServiceEntity using the defined relationship of 'serviceEntities'
Join<RegistryGroupEntity, ServiceEntity> services = registryGroup.join("serviceEntities");

criteriaQuery.multiselect(
        registryGroup.get("id"),
        registryGroup.get("groupName"),
        // use the criteria builder to call the function named 'listagg' and pass parameters in it
        criteriaBuilder.function("listagg", String.class, services.get("name"), criteriaBuilder.literal(",")).alias("serviceNames")
);

// using an aggregate function usually requires a group by to be done
criteriaQuery.groupBy(registryGroup.get("id"), registryGroup.get("groupName"));

RegistryGroupRow registryGroupRow = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getSingleResult();
```

**Result**
Query generated by hibernate:

```
select
    registrygr0_.id as col_0_0_,
    registrygr0_.group_name as col_1_0_,
    LISTAGG(serviceent1_.name, ',') as col_2_0_
from
    registry_group registrygr0_
inner join services serviceent1_ on
    registrygr0_.id = serviceent1_.registry_group_id
group by
    registrygr0_.id ,
    registrygr0_.group_name
```

Result of [`@ToString`](https://projectlombok.org/features/ToString) for the `RegistryGroupRow` retrieved.

```
RegistryGroupRow(id=1, name=RegistryGroup1, serviceNames=ServiceName1,ServiceName2)
```